Determining and labeling unique spans based on Y/N Flag and Continuous Tracking column
Editing question per guidelines as the initial was closed:
I have a large dataset, roughly 500k members over a 12-year span, and I need to determine based on the elig_flag and continuous_elig_counter whether the row for a member in a given month is before their first enrollment (pre-enrollment) or if it is their 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. Enrollment/Unenrollment span. The max number of enrollment spans in the dataset is 11 as I determined by calculating the number of distinct times the elig_counter = 1. The most complicated part appears to be ensuring that the logic tracks with dates when arranged in chronological order.
Dummy data example of desired output:
       Month    ID Elig_Flag Continuous_Elig_Counter Enrollment_Span_Detail
 1:  1/1/2020 XX123         N                       0         Pre-Enrollment
 2:  2/1/2020 XX123         N                       0         Pre-Enrollment
 3:  3/1/2020 XX123         Y                       1       First Enrollment
 4:  4/1/2020 XX123         Y                       2       First Enrollment
 5:  5/1/2020 XX123         Y                       3       First Enrollment
 6:  6/1/2020 XX123         Y                       4       First Enrollment
 7:  7/1/2020 XX123         Y                       5       First Enrollment
 8:  8/1/2020 XX123         N                       0     First Unenrollment
 9:  9/1/2020 XX123         N                       0     First Unenrollment
10: 10/1/2020 XX123         N                       0     First Unenrollment
11: 11/1/2020 XX123         N                       0     First Unenrollment
12: 12/1/2020 XX123         Y                       1      Second Enrollment
13:  1/1/2021 XX123         Y                       2      Second Enrollment
14:  2/1/2021 XX123         Y                       3      Second Enrollment
15:  3/1/2021 XX123         Y                       4      Second Enrollment
16:  4/1/2021 XX123         Y                       5      Second Enrollment
17:  5/1/2021 XX123         Y                       6      Second Enrollment
18:  6/1/2021 XX123         Y                       7      Second Enrollment
19:  7/1/2021 XX123         N                       0    Second Unenrollment
20:  8/1/2021 XX123         Y                       1       Third Enrollment
21:  9/1/2021 XX123         Y                       2       Third Enrollment
22: 10/1/2021 XX123         Y                       3       Third Enrollment
23: 11/1/2021 XX123         Y                       4       Third Enrollment
24: 12/1/2021 XX123         Y                       5       Third Enrollment

I've used lag() in tandem with ifelse statements in similar situations in the past, but this case appears to be a bit more difficult and I haven't had any luck so far.

An approach to show any arbitrary number of Enrollments / "Unenrollments". Based on the order of dates and variable Elig_Flag
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(Elig_Flag, default="") != Elig_Flag & Elig_Flag == "Y"), 
         ESD = case_when(
                 grp == 0 & Elig_Flag == "N" ~ "Pre-Enrollment",
                 grp > 0 & Elig_Flag == "Y" ~ paste0(grp, ". ", "Enrollment"),
                 grp > 0 & Elig_Flag == "N" ~ paste0(grp, ". ", "Unenrollment")), 
         grp = NULL, .by = ID)

output, showing only ID and Enrollment_Span_Detail
      ID Enrollment_Span_Detail             ESD
1  XX123         Pre-Enrollment  Pre-Enrollment
2  XX123         Pre-Enrollment  Pre-Enrollment
3  XX123       First Enrollment   1. Enrollment
4  XX123       First Enrollment   1. Enrollment
5  XX123       First Enrollment   1. Enrollment
6  XX123       First Enrollment   1. Enrollment
7  XX123       First Enrollment   1. Enrollment
8  XX123     First Unenrollment 1. Unenrollment
9  XX123     First Unenrollment 1. Unenrollment
10 XX123     First Unenrollment 1. Unenrollment
11 XX123     First Unenrollment 1. Unenrollment
12 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
13 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
14 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
15 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
16 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
17 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
18 XX123      Second Enrollment   2. Enrollment
19 XX123    Second Unenrollment 2. Unenrollment
20 XX123       Third Enrollment   3. Enrollment
21 XX123       Third Enrollment   3. Enrollment
22 XX123       Third Enrollment   3. Enrollment
23 XX123       Third Enrollment   3. Enrollment
24 XX123       Third Enrollment   3. Enrollment

Data
df <- structure(list(Month = c("1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021"), ID = c("XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123"), Elig_Flag = c("N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), Continuous_Elig_Counter = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Enrollment_Span_Detail = c("Pre-Enrollment", 
"Pre-Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", 
"First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Unenrollment", 
"First Unenrollment", "First Unenrollment", "First Unenrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Unenrollment", "Third Enrollment", 
"Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))


Thanks for the suggestion here. This seems to be getting close to the functionality I need -- but similar to the suggestion posted below by @Carl -- it doesn't work when looking at continuous spans of time. For example, there's a "pre-enrollment' phase that lasts 24 months -- but only the first four months show the "pre-enrollment" value and then there are seemingly random number of rows of different "Unenrollment" values ranging form 1-4, before the first month of enrollment occurs which has the value "5. Enrollment". Any idea on how to ensure the logic also follows the chronological time?

It appears adding arrange(elig_month) in the first pipe before the mutate statement has solved the issue!
df %<>%   arrange(elig_month) %>%   mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(elig_flag, default="") != elig_flag & elig_flag == "Y"),           ESD = case_when(            grp == 0 & elig_flag == "N" ~ "Pre-Enrollment",            grp > 0 & elig_flag == "Y" ~ paste0("Enrollment", "_", grp),            grp > 0 & elig_flag == "N" ~ paste0("Unnrollment", "_", grp)),             grp = NULL, .by = id)

I assumed that was the case because I wrote Based on the order of dates. Good to know you could solve the issue!

You could use consecutive_id to find changes in elig_flag and case_match to apply the values:
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- tibble(
  month = seq(mdy("1/1/2020"), mdy("12/1/2021"), by = "month"),
  id = "XX123",
  elig_flag = c(rep("N", 2), rep("Y", 5), rep("N", 4), rep("Y", 7), rep("N", 1), rep("Y", 5))
)

df |> 
  mutate(
    group = if_else(elig_flag == "N", 0, 1),
    group = consecutive_id(group),
    enroll = case_match(
      group,
      1 ~ "Pre-Enrollment",
      2 ~ "First Enrollment",
      3 ~ "First Unenrollment",
      4 ~ "Second Enrollment",
      5 ~ "Second Unenrollment",
      6 ~ "Third Enrollment",
      .default = "Other"
    ),
    .by = id)
#> # A tibble: 24 × 5
#>    month      id    elig_flag group enroll            
#>    <date>     <chr> <chr>     <int> <chr>             
#>  1 2020-01-01 XX123 N             1 Pre-Enrollment    
#>  2 2020-02-01 XX123 N             1 Pre-Enrollment    
#>  3 2020-03-01 XX123 Y             2 First Enrollment  
#>  4 2020-04-01 XX123 Y             2 First Enrollment  
#>  5 2020-05-01 XX123 Y             2 First Enrollment  
#>  6 2020-06-01 XX123 Y             2 First Enrollment  
#>  7 2020-07-01 XX123 Y             2 First Enrollment  
#>  8 2020-08-01 XX123 N             3 First Unenrollment
#>  9 2020-09-01 XX123 N             3 First Unenrollment
#> 10 2020-10-01 XX123 N             3 First Unenrollment
#> # ℹ 14 more rows

Created on 2024-04-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the solution! I've tested them all and this appears to work closest to what I need. The one issue is that the logic seems to break when I arrange the data by elig_month. The Pre-Enrollment tag works, but when I've picked some sample members I am seeing that, for example, there was a 24 month period of continuous enrollment which should all be "First Enrollment" -- but instead it's showing 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th enrollment and fourth unenrollment during that 24 month period. Do you have any idea what may be causing this? Thanks!

The solution requires them to be in date order, so inserting |> arrange(month) between df and mutate() in my example gives the same result as they were already in date order. In your data, make sure your dates are dates not characters, i.e. class(df$month) should say date not character. If character, then convert to dates with lubridate mdy as per my sample data.

Thank you! I figured that out when testing the solution above and both now appear to work. I appreciate the help!

My contribution: use nombre!
This cool pkg helps to write numbers as cardinals, ordinals, adverbs, numerals, ratios etc.
The complete take:
library(tidyverse)
library(nombre)

# -----------------
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(.by = c(ID), esd = trunc(consecutive_id(Elig_Flag)/2)) %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = c(ID, Elig_Flag),
    esd = case_when(
      Elig_Flag == "N" & esd == 0 ~ "Pre-Enrollment", 
      Elig_Flag == "N" & esd != 0 ~ paste0(nom_ord(esd), " Unenrollment"), # nombre::num_ord
      Elig_Flag == "Y" ~ paste0(nom_ord(esd), " Enrollment")) %>% 
      
      str_to_title()) %>% 
  
  rename(Enrollment_Span_Detail = esd) # That's a big var name 


The output:
> df
       Month    ID Elig_Flag Continuous_Elig_Counter     expected_output Enrollment_Span_Detail
1   1/1/2020 XX123         N                       0      Pre-Enrollment         Pre-Enrollment
2   2/1/2020 XX123         N                       0      Pre-Enrollment         Pre-Enrollment
3   3/1/2020 XX123         Y                       1    First Enrollment       First Enrollment
4   4/1/2020 XX123         Y                       2    First Enrollment       First Enrollment
5   5/1/2020 XX123         Y                       3    First Enrollment       First Enrollment
6   6/1/2020 XX123         Y                       4    First Enrollment       First Enrollment
7   7/1/2020 XX123         Y                       5    First Enrollment       First Enrollment
8   8/1/2020 XX123         N                       0  First Unenrollment     First Unenrollment
9   9/1/2020 XX123         N                       0  First Unenrollment     First Unenrollment
10 10/1/2020 XX123         N                       0  First Unenrollment     First Unenrollment
11 11/1/2020 XX123         N                       0  First Unenrollment     First Unenrollment
12 12/1/2020 XX123         Y                       1   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
13  1/1/2021 XX123         Y                       2   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
14  2/1/2021 XX123         Y                       3   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
15  3/1/2021 XX123         Y                       4   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
16  4/1/2021 XX123         Y                       5   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
17  5/1/2021 XX123         Y                       6   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
18  6/1/2021 XX123         Y                       7   Second Enrollment      Second Enrollment
19  7/1/2021 XX123         N                       0 Second Unenrollment    Second Unenrollment
20  8/1/2021 XX123         Y                       1    Third Enrollment       Third Enrollment
21  9/1/2021 XX123         Y                       2    Third Enrollment       Third Enrollment
22 10/1/2021 XX123         Y                       3    Third Enrollment       Third Enrollment
23 11/1/2021 XX123         Y                       4    Third Enrollment       Third Enrollment
24 12/1/2021 XX123         Y                       5    Third Enrollment       Third Enrollment

Toydata provided by @Andre_Wildberd
df <- structure(list(Month = c("1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021"), ID = c("XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", "XX123", 
"XX123", "XX123"), Elig_Flag = c("N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), Continuous_Elig_Counter = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Enrollment_Span_Detail = c("Pre-Enrollment", 
"Pre-Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", 
"First Enrollment", "First Enrollment", "First Unenrollment", 
"First Unenrollment", "First Unenrollment", "First Unenrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", "Second Enrollment", 
"Second Enrollment", "Second Unenrollment", "Third Enrollment", 
"Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment", "Third Enrollment"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

df <- rename(expected_output = Enrollment_Span_Detail)


